# Master-Slave type Thermostat?

Tags: thermostat

I have 4 thermostats located in four different zones and a separate AC thermostat.

I want to get some programmable thermostats for each location.  I could buy 4 individual programmable thermostats but they're like $100+ each.

Is there some product where one thermostat act as the master with all settings, schedules, etc. and the other thermostats only act as receivers (i.e. they only receive a command to set the temp).

Multizone thermostat (where one single thermostat can control multiple zones) doesn't work since there's no master location (all thermostats are in separate locations).

Comment: You should provide some additional information regarding just what your existing thermostats control. Do you have four completely separate heaters and a separate AC unit? Or is it more like you have two multistage type heaters or heat pumps. This is very important information to know when trying to suggest just what approach to use.

Comment: @MichaelKaras Each thermostat (analog) controls a different zone (i.e. T1 controls Bedroom 1&2, T2 -> Bedroom 3&4, T3 -> Living Room, T4 -> Kitchen and rest).  As far as I know, in the utilities closet there's these four devices with wires coming out of them which I'm told are the individual heating zone controllers.  The AC is completely separate.

Comment: All you have clarified is what your zones are. You need to also be familiar with and expose what type of heater unit(s) that you have. After all you could just have one single stage heater with four sets of duct controls. It kind of sounds like you are in the dark about your overall system configuration. It may be necessary for you to consult with a professional.